# Is it possible to access af function defined on the website with Testcafé?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

Lets say 'mywebsite.com' has a global function:

```
function sayHello(message){
console.log(message)
}
```

is it possible to run a test of that function with testcafé in nodejs?

So far i have this

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `mywebsite test`
    .page `http://mywebsite.com`;

test('sayHelloFuncTest', async t => {

    sayHello('HELLO!')

});
```

This will give me an error saying:  *ReferenceError: sayHello is not defined*

So is there a way to access the sayHello() function?

Comment: testcafe is for simulating user interaction on a webpage. if you wanted to test specific functions, you'll probably want to export the functions you wish to test, and import them into your test script

Comment: I tried that and got a lot of errors like "fetch is not defined".
So it doesn't run as if i just ran it in the browser for some reason.

Is there maybe a more logical way to open a website in browser, run a globally defined function and return errors, with nodeJs

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) to execute some script in the browser.

For example:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
    .page `example.com`;

test('Test', async t => {
    const callSayHello = ClientFunction(() => { sayHello('HELLO!'); });

    await callSayHello();
});
```

or

```
await t.eval(() => { sayHello('HELLO!'); });
```